# What is the IBAN number of an account in Canada?

Tags: canada, banking, wire-transfer, swift, iban

I need to make a wire transfer from Europe to Canada through the banks.

Europe is using IBAN code system for wire transfer. It has a 26 digit code.
Canada is using SWIFT code system for wire transfer. Probably 15 digit code.

The bank in Europe has one input line for IBAN code. How do I put information of SWIFT code equivalent to IBAN?

The following information for Canadian Banks are:
Swift code   : AAAAAAAA  (8-digits)
Clearing code: BBCCCCDDDDD (11-digits)
Institution number : CCCC (4-digits)
Transit number:   DDDDD (5-digit)
Beneficiary number: EEEEEEE (7-digit)

My guess is that one line code (equivalent to IBAN) will be:
BBCCCCDDDDDEEEEEEE (18 - digit number)
Am I correct?

Comment: I changed the title because you are not asking if anyone has done a wire transfer, you are actually asking how to know the IBAN.

Comment: Also, this: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/45545/what-canadian-account-number-format-do-european-banks-need-for-wire-transfer-ins?rq=1

Comment: There is probably a different procedure for payments without an IBAN (or even with an IBAN but outside the European SEPA system), possibly not available online but only by other means (in branch, over the phone…) or requiring some additional service to be enabled on your online banking, and very likely with very different (much higher) fees. This will depend on your bank and possibly account type. You may want to consider alternatives such as Wise for this transfer (at the very least you should compare costs).

Answer (score 3):

There's no 1:1 translation from SWIFT to IBAN, these are different systems with different identifiers. Canadian banks do not use IBANs, so you'll need to use the SWIFT attributes to make a wire transfer. Your European bank should provide you a form for that, you may need to call in or go to a physical branch to complete this transaction.